# Issue on AngularJS directive link and ngHref

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I will try to shorten my problem description as much as possible here.

I have a directive which looks as following

```
scope: false
restrict: "A"
link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
    ...
}
```

and the input parameter `element` looks as following

```
<div class="tab-container" my-directive>
  <div ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.tabs" class="tab">
     <a ng-href="{{tab.name}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

`ng-repeat` has been "resolved", unsure if that the correct term, however `ng-href` has not been resolved, that is, it hasn't turned `{{tab.name}}` to the value I need.

I wonder how I can tell this directive to run link, after `ng-href` has been resolved first.

I read something about `require` property, but it seems to handle `controller` only.

Comment: When I recreate your situation, ng-repeat is not compiled yet. Is there some code that could affect this you're not sharing?
See fiddle: http://jsbin.com/yiqukipeku/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @sniels yes I missed something. I updated your jsbin http://jsbin.com/pelaxebesi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I can get there with a timeout, but I don't think that is a good solution. What is it exactly you're trying to achieve? Maybe there's another way to solve it.

Comment: I'm using a GUI framework similar to bootstrap. And one of the component in there require `href` to exist and be unique. So I need to make `ng-href` work somehow. And yes, `timeout` is not a reliable solution :/

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how I can tell this directive to run link, after ng-href has
>   been resolved first.

You can send [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) event from your controller to directive.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('onHrefReady');
```

and in your directive:

```
link : function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$on("onHrefReady", function (event, args) {
            // do your stuff
        });
    }
```

`link` is called after rendering, so you can call `link` content after got notification from controller

Comment: unsure how I can apply it in my case. I tried it in following jsbin. But it does not register something broadcasted http://jsbin.com/honiqatuwi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @starcorn its happens because you call `$broadcast` when directive is still not rendered. set some timeout 10ms to simulate right behaviour.  http://jsbin.com/fizasuhewi/1/edit?html,js,console,output